# AWS IAM custom policy for compound values in a key not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Trying to implement the AWS IAM tag based custom policy for below scenarios but it's not working for me.

1. Let's say user is having a tag where key is Environment with multiple value(- is delimiter for combine environment tag value) for this tag. Like:

   [image]
2. There are two EC2 instance which is having Environment tag key with following value:

```
   Instance Name       Key            Value

a) EC2 instance - 1    Environment    Dev

b) EC2 instance - 2    Environment    Prod
```

3. Below is policy JSON condition which is not working. Policy Name : A

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17", 

    "Statement": [

        {
            "Sid": "AllowStopStartEC2ForAll",

            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Environment": "${aws:PrincipalTag/Environment}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As per my requirement. User which is having policy A should be able to start/stop EC2 instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your policy is based on [Simplify granting access to your AWS resources by using tags on AWS IAM users and roles | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/simplify-granting-access-to-your-aws-resources-by-using-tags-on-aws-iam-users-and-roles/).

However, that example was checking whether a string was **equal**:

```
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/CostCenter": "${aws:PrincipalTag/CostCenter}"
                }
            }
```

In your case, you wish to use `StringLike`. When doing so, it checks whether the right-side expression is *found within* the left-side expression.

In your situation, you have:

- User tag: `Dev-Prod`
- Instance tag: `Dev`

Therefore, the left and right sides of the expression need to be swapped, and **a wildcard added** to work with `StringLike`:

```
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalTag/Environment": "*${ec2:ResourceTag/Environment}*"
                }
            }
```

The complete policy to use is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowStopStartEC2ForAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalTag/Environment": "*${ec2:ResourceTag/Environment}*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```